# Why does the input .val() disappear once submitted - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Why does the HTML value here disappear in the .name div almost straight after the function is executed?

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
    value = $("#txtName").val();
    $(".name").text(value);
});
```

Comment: is it still doing a full post back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there's no other code on the page, your code isn't canceling the postback which will re-load the page. You could call `e.preventDefault();` on the first line of the handler to prevent submission.

A better option would be to handle the [`submit()` event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) of the form rather than listening for any clicks on submit buttons. This will properly handle a form submission from all sources (keypress, etc.):

```
$('#yourFormId').submit(function(){
    value = $('#txtName').val();
    $('.name').text(value);
    return false; // prevents submission
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A post back is occurring, cancel the default action:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    value = $("#txtName").val();
    $(".name").text(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This happen because you have a Submit action that supmit the form collection and reset your fields.
To resolve this problem change your code as following :

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
value = $("#txtName").val();
$(".name").text(value);

// if you would like to submit then :
$('form').submit();
```

});